# My Nokia Lumia 630 is hanged during update....!

Tags: update, nokia-lumia-630

My Nokia Lumia 630 shows a update, when I had downloaded files and installed it, It's only rolling. I can't access my phone anymore. I'd tried to hard reset by power bottom and volume down key, but it's doesn't work. What should I do? Please help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect charger to your phone. And wait for some more time. In my case my phone was taken 1 hour to complete the process.

Comment: I'd tried for six hours... It's doesn't work...!!

Comment: So reset solved your problem? Let me know.

Comment: No it still rolling till now.....!!!!

Comment: You can use Windows device recovery tool to reinstall the software version on the your phone. https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq